# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am getting this error:

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   An error occurred while sending
> the request.   Unable to connect to the remote server   A connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond 185.82.212.95:8080

Comment: I am able to access it now.  Are you still having a problem?

Comment: No. The problem is resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @CliveCiappara This solution is worked for me, Internet Explorer > Tools > Connections > Lan Settings
Uncheck 'Automatically Detect Settings' box. This solved the Nuget Package Manager issue for me.

Comment: i am still having the same problem and also tried the 'Internet Explorer > Tools > Connections > Lan Settings Uncheck 'Automatically Detect Settings' box'  what should i do now?

Answer (score 27):

I was having same issue in VS 2017. You would need to enable proxy settings for VS, so that it can use existing IE proxy to reach out internet. This is especially useful, for those users, who uses office laptops and proxy settings are managed by group policies and IE settings get updated automatically. It would have been great if there was an option within VS IDE itself to add proxy just like Eclipse IDE has.

**Solution**

1. Go to your Visual Studio install location as below -

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE

2. Open **devenv.exe.config** file as an Administrator.

Add **defaultProxy** tags as below, within the existing system.net tag -

```xml
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
  <settings>
    <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

3. Restart VS.

Comment: Please mark this as answer, if the mentioned steps resolved your issue, thanks.

Comment: It's the accepted answer for me, it resolved cleanly. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad that I could help you. Can you please mark this as answer.

Comment: I wish I could, but it's up to the OP to accept the answer. According to the comments, he managed to solve it by another fix.

Comment: This solved my problem an saved my day .you r my hero :)

Answer (score 19):

**TLDR ;)**

Ok, let's get started to fix this issue :)

First, you need to navigate the Visual Studio instance and for that do the following:

1. Open Properties on VS shortcut and then click on "Open File Location"

   [image]
2. Edit **as administrator** the `devenv.exe.config` with Notepad++ or other editors you prefer:

   [image]
3. Navigate to the end of a file and check if you don't have `<defaultProxy>...` section:

   [image]
4. Make sure to add following inside `<system.net>`:

```xml
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
```

---

The final result should be like this:

[image]

**A few notes:**

1. If you have several Visual Studio instances then make sure you edited  `devenv.exe.config` for each one.
2. Sometimes after VS updates, these files content can reset. So a good hint here is that once you Update Visual Studio instance, then go and check the `.exe.config` file.

---

**Update:**
Btw, the same kind of approach work for many other applications, for example, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61464698/806202) post.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem with **VS 2015** Go to the following folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

and add In my case  is already present added the highlighted text

```xml
<system.net>
    **<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>**
  <settings>
    <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using VSTS as source provider (git). Was logged in to a MSDN account in VS2017 based on the correct email address, i.e. same as the one used for my VSTS login. Upon restoring packages from the VSTS nuget-feed, I would repeatedly be prompted to log in to my MSDN-account, but still get 401 from the source/feed.

Turned out, I apparently had [2 different MSDN-accounts](http://www.brucebnews.com/2016/06/finding-your-way-through-microsofts-maze-of-work-and-personal-accounts/) on the same email address - 1 "Personal" account and 1 "Work or school" account.

Solution: simply log in with the correct one (which here turned out to be the Work one)

Answer (score 0):

The same error is showing for VS2019.
For my case Restart the Visual Studio and it's working fine.
In my case, it's the network-related issue, you have a proper Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

## Another method - a workaround - Just do it manually!

I gave up all solutions provided in Github an SO.
Checking the [Manage .NET project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/templates) docs I just found out that I can install a package locally.

So if anyone is struggling with this, just download `.nupkg` the package from the source and use the following command

```
dotnet new -i c:\some-folder\some-package.nupkg
```

### How to download a package manually

1. Go to [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages)
2. Search for your package and click to see the details
3. Locate the **Download package**  link, located at the **Info** section.
4. Use the command shown above. Cheers! Package installed!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error intermittently and the devenv.exe.config fix suggested above did not fix it for me. I tried the terminal command below which ran successfully:

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

Subsequent publishes through the IDE were successful. So for me this error seems to be the result of something being cached. I am not sure what starts it.

Answer (score -2):

Please go to [Nuget.org](https://status.nuget.org/) and check if the Nuget is up.

[image]