# Can not connect to nuget

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I can not connect to nuget.org in my visual studio 2017 and i can not install any package from nuget.
the error is :

Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Comment: Does the URL work for you in your browser? If it doesn't then you know it's your PC as a whole or your ISP doing something fishy. If it does, then it's something with nuget itself.

Comment: I think you might find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500032/unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source-https-api-nuget-org-v3-index-json)

Comment: Matt -  Yes it works.

Comment: Mutasim Malik - it is not the true solution