# Login to Power BI with Power shell throws error "System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'localhost.fiddler'"

Tags: powershell, authentication, powerbi, fiddler

When I'm trying to login to **Power BI** with Microsoft **Power Shell ISE**:

```
Login-PowerBI
```

from the Package: [MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps),
I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to get ADAL token: Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The r 
>      emote name could not be resolved: 'localhost.fiddler'   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse...

Comment: looks like its DNS problem. What is localhost.fiddler ? I think you shoul check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio [NuGet service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55919145/806202).

When PowerShell tries to log in to **Power BI** account (when executing command `Login-PowerBI`), it executes `AzureADWindowsAuthenticator.exe`, which looks for the configuration under:
 `MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile` → `version of power bi profile` → `lib` → `netstandard`→ `WindowsAuthenticator` directory.

> The configuration file is called  `AzureADWindowsAuthenticator.exe.config`.

To solve the problem edit the configuration file as **Administrator** and add the following under `<configuration>` section:

```xml
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
   <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
   </settings>
</system.net>
```

---

*The final result should be like this:*

[image]